# top/bottom have no effect on relative positioned element

Tags: html, css

The problem is this one: even if the html class "didascalia" is relative positioned, and the same for its father class "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 spaziatura", I can't move with top and bottom the "didascalia" class and I don't know why. I would like for example to move it more at the top in order to be aligned more or less with the top border of its father, but the element doesn't move. Any idea? thank you very much!

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

#navbar {
  margin-bottom:0; }

.alert {
  border-radius: 0; }

.container {
  width:100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, 
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, 
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, 
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, 
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, 
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, 
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, 
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, 
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, 
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, 
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, 
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0; }

.row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0; }

.footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-top: none; }

.panel {
  border:none; }

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*ALLARTICLES*/

.articlecontainer{
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    
    
} @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .articlecontainer {
      margin: 0;
    }}
 
/*ARTICLESFIRSTLINE*/

.articlesfirtsline{
      height: 20%;} 
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .articlesfirtsline {
      height: 10%;
    }}

.images {
    display: block;
    width:90%; 
    position: relative; 
    left:5%;   
    max-height: 116.547px;
    height: 110px;

} @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .images {
      width: 72px;
      height: 72px;
      float: left;
      left: 3%;
    }}

h3.articlestitle{ 
    color:rgb(255, 68, 34);
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative; 
    left:1.1%;  
    
}

.didascalia{ 
   position: relative;
   left:5%;
   width: 90%;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
}  @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .didascalia {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 17px;
      width: 70%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 1%;

      

    }}

    

@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .spaziatura {
       padding-bottom: 5%;
    }}


.autore li {
  
  display: inline;
  color: #AAA;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;

} 

.autore {
  
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;

} 

.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="articlecontainer clearfix">  
      <br><br>
      <h3 class="articlestitle">Latest News</h3>
      <br>
      <div class="articlesfirtsline clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 spaziatura">
          <img src="https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/08/Terminator-3-540x270.jpg" class="images">
          <br>
          <h4 class="didascalia">Take pictures like a pro with this Hollywood Art Institute training for under $20</h4>  
          <br>
          <ul class="autore">
            <li>Rachel Kaser - </li>
            <li> 13 hours ago </li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem when using height or relative positioning ,based on percentage, is that all the parents must have a height set to them as well.

this would work: https://jsfiddle.net/2esovvpc/

```
html,body {
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

#navbar {
  margin-bottom:0; }

.alert {
  border-radius: 0; }

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, 
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, 
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, 
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, 
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, 
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, 
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, 
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, 
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, 
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, 
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, 
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0; }

.row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0; }

.footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-top: none; }

.panel {
  border:none; }



html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}








/*ALLARTICLES*/

.articlecontainer{
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 100%;


} @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .articlecontainer {
      margin: 0;
    }}

/*ARTICLESFIRSTLINE*/

.articlesfirtsline{
      height: 20%;} 
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .articlesfirtsline {
      height: 10%;
    }}

.images {
    display: block;
    width:90%; 
    position: relative; 
    left:5%;   
    max-height: 116.547px;
    height: 110px;

} @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .images {
      width: 72px;
      height: 72px;
      float: left;
      left: 3%;
    }}

h3.articlestitle{ 
    color:rgb(255, 68, 34);
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative; 
    left:1.1%;  

}

.didascalia{ 
   position: relative;
   top: 20%;
   left:5%;
   width: 90%;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
}  @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .didascalia {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 17px;
      width: 70%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 1%;



    }}



@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .spaziatura {
       padding-bottom: 5%;
    }}


.autore li {

  display: inline;
  color: #AAA;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;

} 

.autore {

  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;

} 







.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```